# Windows 7 based computer resolves to IP address of old server - site works properly on other devices

Tags: windows-7, dns

I recently moved two websites from one web hosting account to another. My desktop, which is running Windows 7 Professional, resolves to the old IP address from the previous hosting server for 1 out of 2 of the sites that I moved. The 2nd site on the same hosting account works fine from my desktop.

I have run `ping speedrak.com` in my command prompt and it resolves to the old IP address, yet I run `nslookup speedrak.com` and it shows the proper IP address.

The website SpeedRak.com works fine on every other device I use. I have tried all different browsers, cleared cache, flushed my DNS cache, put my 'Hosts' file back to its original state, ran disk cleanup deleting all Temp files, etc. Nothing has worked.

Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 0):

I would first understand if its a dns issue or hosts file issue.
I would open N elevated command prompt and do a ipconfig /flushdns followed by ipconfig /displaydns > c:\dns.txt
Then I would check if dns resolution was correct. If not, then I would change the dns server to match the working PC and check again. If its dns then we will need to understand which dns server is returning the wrong value.

If dns.txt does not have an entry for your site, it's mostly a host file issue

Comment: Thank You Ganesh for taking the time to help me with this situation.

I am new to all this and I wasn't sure what 'N Elevated Command Prompt' was, so I researched it and came up with Running as Administrator in the command prompt.

I flushed the cache, then ran the displaydns you show above and got nothing in return except for C:\Windows\system32\.

Comment: Running 'ping speedrak.com' still shows the old IP address of the old server hosting.

I went to my Hosts file from Notepad, Ran as Administrator and all is in its original state, no modifications.

Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: Did you check if a file called dns.txt was created on C:\. It should contain all dns entries. Check if dns entry for your website is present

Comment: I did run as you stated above 'ipconfig /displaydns > c:\dns.txt' and it showed nothing. Is there another way to find out?

Comment: Ironically, right after I wrote to you, I thought I'd run a local search for 'dns.txt' and it opened up a text file just like you thought. I scrolled down and found the IP address that it is resolving to. I am going to delete the entry and save it with the hopes of this issue being resolved.

Comment: Deleting the entry from dns.txt will not help as it is the output of displaydns. But that confirms that your dns is returning the wrong ip. Can you change the dns set for your network adapter to match the dns from other working mache or set it to 8.8.8.8, run flushdns and try again?

Comment: The IPv4 DNS servers are already set to 8.8.8.8 for the Preferred and 8.8.4.4 for the Alternate.

Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes. Is this the same dns on the working PC?

Comment: Also are both the pcs in the same region. Some hosting providers provide edge dns servers for each region that may provide different ip for same address for performance

Comment: If I'm looking it up correctly on my Macbook Pro, the DNS servers are 192.168.1.1.

TCP/IP says the IPv4 Address is: 192.168.1.16

All my computers and devices are in the same location and using the same WiFi network...

Comment: Then the dns server is your Router.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me Ganesh, I am new to this and am doing my best to resolve this issue, but am not sure what I am supposed to be looking for or do next.

I don't know if it helps when you mention the DNS server as the router, but I recently moved, hooked up a brand new modem/router combination. This issue has been doing this prior to moving with a different router combination. Considering the other devices work using the same installed router, I'm assuming that isn't part of the issue?

Comment: Should not be...

Comment: I did a dns query check and the ip seems to be returned by siteground. Is that correct? See https://simpledns.com/lookup-dg.

Comment: Also in the nslookup, without manually changing the dns server in the network adapter, is the ip returned by the same dns server? Basically is the server field same or from a similar company? On both working and non working pc

Comment: Yes... I checked both of my sites via the simpledns website you provided above and everything seemed identical for IP addresses and DNS.

If I am understanding your questions correctly, when I run the 'NSLookup' via command prompt via either computer, it is returning the proper IP address for where the website, speedrak.com is located. It's the identical IP for my other site on the same hosting, so that is working correctly. It's only when I run 'ping speedrak.com' that it returns the old IP address for my previous hosting account - on my Desktop computer only.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161005/how-does-ping-resolves-ip-address have you updated hosts file or resolve.conf file?